# How can I take items from a listbox and display them in a listview in another form?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a listbox full of items for my order.

I want to take all of the items inside my listbox and transfer them into my listview.

Then I want to take my listview and display it in another form (my messagebox).

My new listview:

```
private void CustomerInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem customers = new ListViewItem(fullName.Text);

        customers.SubItems.Add(totalcount.ToString());
        customers.SubItems.Add(total.ToString());
        customers.SubItems.Add(Address.Text);
        customers.SubItems.Add(telephone.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i < OrderlistBox.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            customers.SubItems.Add(OrderlistBox.Items[i].ToString());
        }

        Customers.Items.Add(customers);

        //CLEAR ALL FIELDS
        OrderlistBox.Items.Clear();
        fullName.Text = "";
        Address.Text = "";
        telephone.Text = "";
        totalDue.Text = "";
        totalItems.Text = "";
    }
```

My contextMenuStrip, so when I click on the customer I can get its info (name, address, order, etc.):

```
private void customerInformationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Customers.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            var myformmessagedialog = new MessageBoxForm
            {
                name = Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text,
                address = Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text,
                telephone = Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text,
            };
            myformmessagedialog.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

My new form, the messagebox where I will display all the info for the client:

```
  public partial class MessageBoxForm : Form
  {
    public MessageBoxForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string name;
    public string address;
    public string telephone;
    public ListViewItem order = new ListViewItem();

    private void MessageBoxForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lblName.Text = name;
        lbladdress.Text = address;
        lbltelephone.Text = telephone;

        orderListView.Items.Add(order);
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if this seems confusing but I'm just looking for help to go in the right direction. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way based on your current setup is to simply pass your list view data across to your `MessageBoxForm` e.g.

```
public partial class MessageBoxForm : Form
{
    ...

    public void LoadListView(ListViewItemCollection items)
    {
        orderListView.Clear();
        orderListView.AddRange(items);
    }
}

....

private void customerInformationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{    
    if (Customers.SelectedItems.Count != 0)    
    {    
        var myformmessagedialog = new MessageBoxForm    
        {    
            name = Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text,    
            address = Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text,    
            telephone = Customers.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text,    
        };
        myformmessagedialog.LoadListView(Customers.Items);
        myformmessagedialog.ShowDialog();    
    }    
}
```

Comment: This is what im looking to do is pass the customers items but it's not working.

Comment: I'm at work but I can't remember the specific error, I know it was something to do with the public void loadlistview(listviewitemcollection items). I think it wouldn't let me call listviewitemcollection, am I missing a system thing?

Comment: @ClaudiuBadau include `System.Windows.Forms.ListView` in your namespaces, the `ListViewItemCollection` class is in there.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out eventually.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to put the data that you want to display in some sort of ViewModel, basically a class or set of classes that has the data that you want to display.  Then the main form can display it, and you can pass a reference to that ViewModel to the message box and it can display it as well.

In general you want to avoid any kind of code that directly ties controls from different forms together.

Comment: This sounds most practical but I'm just looking for a current fix with my set up now and then i'll modify the program another time. I just started learning c# and forms so this is what I have so far.

Comment: @ClaudiuBadau - this falls into the "pay me now or pay me later" tradeoff.  However, you can just extract the data you need and send that in a data structure of some sort to your message box.

Answer (score 1):

Basic answer is you don't.

You maintain a collection of items (whatever they are).

You display them in a list box.

You display them in a list view.

If you want say select some from the list box and only move them to the list view.

Then you use the listbox selection to find them in your collections of items, create a list of selected ones then passs that to the form with the listview to display.

Don't use UI controls to store your data and try really hard to never make one form's UI directly dependant on another.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you'd need (and I could have misunderstood what you are looking for) is a new method in you `MessageBoxForm` to pass in your `Customers` object:

```
private void customerInformationToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Customers.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
    {
        var myformmessagedialog = new MessageBoxForm;
        myformmessagedialog.Customers = Customers;
        if (myformmessagedialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
          Customers = myformmessagedialog.Customers;
        }
    }
}
```

If so, simply modify your class to be something like this:

```
public partial class MessageBoxForm : Form
{
  public MessageBoxForm()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void MessageBoxForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (Customers != null) 
    {
      // add your code here to add your Customers as needed
    }
  }

  public Customers Customers { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access anything from the parent form you need to pass it to the child form so

```
myformmessagedialog.ShowDialog();
```

becomes

```
myformmessagedialog dialog = new myformmessagedialg(this);
dialog.ShowDialog();
```

and your class constructor becomes this:

```
public MessageBoxForm(myformmessagedialog parent){
    name=parent.fullName.Text;
    address=parent.address.Text;
    ...etc...
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Though it might be better to just pass in the name, address, etc rather than the whole form, this way is nice for while you are changing things because you have one less place to change to add another variable to pass.